# Use of Cron jobs in Google App Engine

Tags: google-app-engine, cron

How can I use Cron on Google App Engine?

Answer (score 36):

Google has officially enabled cron in the AppEngine, for more details check:

Cron for Python:
http://code.google.com/appengine/docs/python/config/cron.html

Cron for Java:
http://code.google.com/appengine/docs/java/config/cron.html

Comment: And now you can do it using a cloud function: https://firebase.googleblog.com/2019/04/schedule-cloud-functions-firebase-cron.html

Answer (score 3):

[This page](http://groups.google.com/group/httpmr-discuss/browse_thread/thread/1648611a54c01aa) lists how to achieve Cron-like functionality on Google Appengine.

Answer (score 3):

You can now run scheduled tasks with google appengine

http://code.google.com/appengine/docs/python/config/cron.html#Securing_URLs_for_Cron

Answer (score 1):

Read comments to [issue 6](http://code.google.com/p/googleappengine/issues/detail?id=6) for possible workarounds.

Comment: All suggested workarounds in that link depend on external box. The answer 1 suggests a work around without an external box

Answer (score 1):

Use http://schedulerservice.appspot.com/ or http://code.google.com/p/gaeutilities/wiki/Cron

Answer (score 1):

See [this post](http://groups.google.com/group/google-appengine/msg/9a94aaf4a3b9415f) - maybe soon we'll get sort-of-cron functionality in GAE.

Answer (score 1):

According to the official AppEngine blog's public [roadmap update](http://googleappengine.blogspot.com/2009/02/roadmap-update.html) two weeks ago, scheduled tasks (as well as background task queues) are due for the release in the moderately near future ("in the next six months," as of Feb. 6, 2009).

Answer (score 1):

Here is an example http://cron-tab.appspot.com/, the python source code is available in the related project at code.google.com/p/cron-tab/

Answer (score -1):

Here's a tutorial on using a Google App Engine Cron Job to send an automated email:

http://www.fishbonecloud.com/2010/11/automated-email-using-google-app-engine.html

Answer (score -1):

You can use GAE Cron jobs, but be careful as they don't support HTTPS!