# Background tasks on App Engine

Tags: python, google-app-engine, cron

How can I run background tasks on App Engine?

Comment: You should probably remove the php tag, since php doesn't work on GAE.

Answer (score 12):

You may use the [Task Queue Python API](http://code.google.com/appengine/docs/python/taskqueue/).

Answer (score 4):

GAE is very useful tool to build scalable web applications. Few of the limitations pointed out by many are no support for background tasks, lack of periodic tasks and strict limit on how much time each HTTP request takes, if a request exceeds that time limit the operation is terminated, which makes running time consuming tasks impossible.

**How to run background task ?**
In GAE the code is executed only when there is a HTTP request. There is a strict time limit (i think 10secs) on how long the code can take. So if there are no requests then code is not executed. One of the suggested work around was use an external box to send requests continuously, so kind of creating a background task. But for this we need an external box and now we dependent on one more element. The other alternative was sending 302 redirect response so that client re-sends the request, this also makes us dependent on external element which is client. What if that external box is GAE itself ? Everyone who has used functional language which does not support looping construct in the language is aware of the alternative ie recursion is the replacement to loop. So what if we complete part of the computation and do a HTTP GET on the same url with very short time out say 1 second ? This creates a loop(recursion) on php code running on apache.

```
<?php
$i = 0;
if(isset($_REQUEST["i"])){
        $i= $_REQUEST["i"];
    sleep(1);
}
$ch = curl_init("http://localhost".$_SERVER["PHP_SELF"]."?i=".($i+1));
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 0);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 1);
curl_exec($ch);
print "hello world\n";
?>
```

Some how this does not work on GAE. So what if we do HTTP GET on some other url say url2 which does HTTP GET on the first url ? This seem to work in GAE. Code for this looks like this.

```
class FirstUrl(webapp.RequestHandler):
    def get(self):
        self.response.out.write("ok")
        time.sleep(2)
        urlfetch.fetch("http://"+self.request.headers["HOST"]+'/url2')

class SecondUrl(webapp.RequestHandler):
    def get(self):
        self.response.out.write("ok")
        time.sleep(2)
        urlfetch.fetch("http://"+self.request.headers["HOST"]+'/url1')

application = webapp.WSGIApplication([('/url1', FirstUrl), ('/url2', SecondUrl)])
def main():
    run_wsgi_app(application)
if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

Since we found out a way to run background task, lets build abstractions for periodic task (timer) and a looping construct which spans across many HTTP requests (foreach).

**Timer**
Now building timer is straight forward. Basic idea is to have list of timers and the interval at which each should be called. Once we reach that interval call the callback function. We will use memcache to maintain the timer list. To find out when to call callback, we will store a key in memcache with interval as expiration time. We periodically (say 5secs) check if that key is present, if not present then call the callback and again set that key with interval.

```
def timer(func, interval):
    timerlist = memcache.get('timer')
    if(None == timerlist):
        timerlist = []
    timerlist.append({'func':func, 'interval':interval})
    memcache.set('timer-'+func, '1', interval)
    memcache.set('timer', timerlist)

def checktimers():
    timerlist = memcache.get('timer')
    if(None == timerlist):
        return False
    for current in timerlist:
        if(None == memcache.get('timer-'+current['func'])):
            #reset interval
            memcache.set('timer-'+current['func'], '1', current['interval'])
            #invoke callback function
            try:
                eval(current['func']+'()')
            except:
                pass
            return True
    return False
```

**Foreach**
This is needed when we want to do long taking computation say doing some operation on 1000 database rows or fetch 1000 urls etc. Basic idea is to maintain list of callbacks and arguments in memcache and each time invoke callback with the argument.

```
def foreach(func, args):
    looplist = memcache.get('foreach')
    if(None == looplist):
        looplist = []
    looplist.append({'func':func, 'args':args})
    memcache.set('foreach', looplist)

def checkloops():
    looplist = memcache.get('foreach')
    if(None == looplist):
        return False
    if((len(looplist) > 0) and (len(looplist[0]['args']) > 0)):
        arg = looplist[0]['args'].pop(0)
        func = looplist[0]['func']
        if(len(looplist[0]['args']) == 0):
            looplist.pop(0)
        if((len(looplist) > 0) and (len(looplist[0]['args']) > 0)):
            memcache.set('foreach', looplist)
        else:
            memcache.delete('foreach')
        try:
            eval(func+'('+repr(arg)+')')
        except:
            pass
        return True
    else:
        return False

# instead of
# foreach index in range(0, 1000):
#   someoperaton(index)
# we will say
# foreach('someoperaton', range(0, 1000))
```

Now building a program which fetches list of urls every one hour is straight forward. Here is the code.

```
def getone(url):
    try:
        result = urlfetch.fetch(url)
        if(result.status_code == 200):
            memcache.set(url, '1', 60*60)
            #process result.content
    except :
        pass

def getallurl():
    #list of urls to be fetched
    urllist = ['http://www.google.com/', 'http://www.cnn.com/', 'http://www.yahoo.com', 'http://news.google.com']
    fetchlist = []
    for url in urllist:
        if (memcache.get(url) is None):
            fetchlist.append(url)
    #this is equivalent to
    #for url in fetchlist: getone(url)
    if(len(fetchlist) > 0):
        foreach('getone', fetchlist)

#register the timer callback
timer('getallurl', 3*60)
```

complete code is here http://groups.google.com/group/httpmr-discuss/t/1648611a54c01aa
I have been running this code on appengine for few days without much problem.

Warning: We make heavy use of urlfetch. The limit on no of urlfetch per day is 160000. So be careful not to reach that limit.

Comment: I don't see how it can possibly work. Won't you exceed 10 second quota on 6th recursive fetch?

Comment: Correct me if I am wrong, isn't there an AppEngine policy about inter-communication between hosted apps?

Comment: Use the new Task API or the Cron API.  do not use the ones above.

Answer (score 4):

You can find more about cron jobs in Python App Engine [here](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/python/config/cron).

Answer (score 2):

Up and coming version of runtime will have some kind of periodic execution engine a'la cron. See [this message](http://groups.google.com/group/google-appengine/msg/9a94aaf4a3b9415f) on AppEngine group.

> So, all the SDK pieces appear to work, but my testing indicates this isn't running on the production servers yet-- I set up an "every 1 minutes" cron that logs when it runs, and it hasn't been called yet

Hard to say when this will be available, though...

Answer (score 1):

Using the [Deferred Python Library](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/articles/deferred?hl=en) is the easiest way of doing background task on Appengine using Python which is built on top of TaskQueue API.

```
from google.appengine.ext import deferred

def do_something_expensive(a, b, c=None):
    logging.info("Doing something expensive!")
    # Do your work here

# Somewhere else
deferred.defer(do_something_expensive, "Hello, world!", 42, c=True)
```

Comment: There are pros and cons for using the deferred library, see "When to use ext.deferred" section in Nick Johnson's article: https://cloud.google.com/appengine/articles/deferred?hl=en

Answer (score 0):

If you want to run background periodic tasks, see [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/145651/cron-jobs-on-google-appengine) (AppEngine cron)

If your tasks are not periodic, see [Task Queue Python API](http://code.google.com/appengine/docs/python/taskqueue/) or [Task Queue Java API](http://code.google.com/appengine/docs/java/taskqueue/)

Answer (score 0):

There is a cron facility built into app engine.

Please refer to:
https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/python/config/cron?hl=en

Answer (score -3):

Use the Task Queue - http://code.google.com/appengine/docs/java/taskqueue/overview.html

Comment: -1; this is essentially the same answer posted and accepted 2 years ago, with a link to the Java docs instead of the Python docs, when the OP was using Python. Seriously?