# What alternatives are there to Google App Engine?

Tags: google-app-engine, cloud

What alternatives are there to GAE, given that I already have a good bit of code working that I would like to keep.  In other words, I'm digging python.  However, my use case is more of a low number of requests, higher CPU usage type use case, and I'm worried that I may not be able to stay with App Engine forever.  I have heard a lot of people talking about Amazon Web Services and other sorts of cloud providers, but I am having a hard time seeing where most of these other offerings provide the range of services (data querying, user authentication, automatic scaling) that App Engine provides.  What are my options here?

Comment: Old question. But Azure App Service provides similar Development PaaS Stack: https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/services/app-service/

Answer (score 24, accepted):

I don't think there is another alternative (with regards to code portability) to GAE right now since GAE is in a class of its own. Sure GAE is cloud computing, but I see GAE as a subset of cloud computing. Amazon's EC2 is also cloud computing (as well as Joyent Accelerators, Slicehost Slices), but obviously they are two different beasts as well. So right now you're in a situation that requires rethinking your architecture depending on your needs.

The immediate benefits of GAE is that its essentially maintenance free as it relates to infrastructure (scalable web server and database administration). GAE is more tailored to those developers that only want to focus on their applications and not the underlying system.In a way you can consider that developer friendly. Now it should also be said that these other cloud computing solutions also try to allow you to only worry about your application as much as you like by providing VM images/templates. Ultimately your needs will dictate the approach you should take.

Now with all this in mind we can also construct hybrid solutions and workarounds that might fulfill our needs as well. For example, GAE doesn't seem *directly* suited to this specific app needs you describe. In other words, GAE offers relatively high number of requests, low number of cpu cycles (not sure if paid version will be any different).

However, one way to tackle this challenge is by building a customized solution involving GAE as the front end and Amazon AWS (EC2, S3, and SQS) as the backend. Some will say you might as well build your entire stack on AWS, but that may involve rewriting lots of existing code as well. Furthermore, as a workaround a previous [stackoverflow post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/149307/background-tasks-on-appengine) describes a method of simulating background tasks in GAE. Furthermore, you can look into [HTTP Map/Reduce](http://code.google.com/p/httpmr/) to distribute workload as well.

Answer (score 31):

**AppScale**

AppScale is a platform that allows users to deploy and host their own Google App Engine applications. It executes automatically over Amazon EC2 and Eucalyptus as well as Xen and KVM. It has been developed and is maintained by [AppScale Systems](http://appscale.com). It supports the Python, Go, PHP, and Java Google App Engine platforms.

http://github.com/AppScale/appscale

## In the mean time...

...it is amost 2015 and it seems that containers are the way to go forward. Alternatives to GAE are emerging:

Google has released [Kubernetes](http://kubernetes.io/), container scheduling software developed by them to [manage GCE containers](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/containers), but can be used on other clusters as well.

There are some [upcoming PaaS](http://thenewstack.io/docker-is-driving-a-new-breed-of-paas/) on Docker such as

- http://deis.io/
- http://www.tsuru.io/
- [even Appscale themselves are supporting Docker](http://www.appscale.com/2013/10/30/appscale-on-docker/)

Interesting stuff to keep an eye on.

Answer (score 6):

As of 2016, if you're willing to lump [PaaS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Platform_as_a_service) (platform as a service) and [FaaS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Function_as_a_Service) (function as a service) in the same [serverless computing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Serverless_computing) category, then you have a few FaaS options.

### Proprietary

#### [AWS Lambda](https://aws.amazon.com/lambda/)

> AWS Lambda lets you run code without provisioning or managing servers. You pay only for the compute time you consume - there is no charge when your code is not running. With Lambda, you can run code for virtually any type of application or backend service - all with zero administration. Just upload your code and Lambda takes care of everything required to run and scale your code with high availability. You can set up your code to automatically trigger from other AWS services or call it directly from any web or mobile app.

**AWS Step Functions** complements AWS Lambda.

> AWS Step Functions makes it easy to coordinate the components of distributed applications and microservices using visual workflows. Building applications from individual components that each perform a discrete function lets you scale and change applications quickly. Step Functions is a reliable way to coordinate components and step through the functions of your application. Step Functions provides a graphical console to arrange and visualize the components of your application as a series of steps. This makes it simple to build and run multi-step applications. Step Functions automatically triggers and tracks each step, and retries when there are errors, so your application executes in order and as expected. Step Functions logs the state of each step, so when things do go wrong, you can diagnose and debug problems quickly. You can change and add steps without even writing code

#### [Google Cloud Functions](https://cloud.google.com/functions/)

As of 2016 it is in alpha.

> Google Cloud Functions is a lightweight, event-based, asynchronous compute solution that allows you to create small, single-purpose functions that respond to cloud events without the need to manage a server or a runtime environment. Events from Google Cloud Storage and Google Cloud Pub/Sub can trigger Cloud Functions asynchronously, or you can use HTTP invocation for synchronous execution.

#### [Azure Functions](https://functions.azure.com/)

> An event-based serverless compute experience to accelerate your development. It can scale based on demand and you pay only for the resources you consume.

### Open

#### [Serverless](https://serverless.com/)

> The Serverless Framework allows you to deploy auto-scaling, pay-per-execution, event-driven functions to any cloud. We currently support Amazon Web Service's Lambda, and are expanding to support other cloud providers.

#### [IronFunctions](http://open.iron.io/)

> IronFunctions is an open source serverless computing platform for any cloud - private, public, or hybrid.

---

It remains to seen how well FaaS competes with CaaS (container as a service). The former seems more lightweight. Both seem suited to microservices architectures.

I anticipate that functions (as in FaaS) are not the end of the line, and that many years forward we'll see further service abstractions, e.g. test-only development, followed by plain-language scenarios.

Answer (score 5):

Alternatives:
 1. [AppScale](http://www.appscale.com/)
 2. [Heroku](https://www.heroku.com/).

Ref: [Alternative for Google AppEngine?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3444911/alternative-for-google-appengine)

Answer (score 3):

Amazon's Elastic Compute Cloud or EC2 is a good option.  You basically run Linux VMs on their servers that you can control via a web interface (for powering up and down) and of course access via SSH or whatever you normally set up...
And as it's a linux install that you control, you can of course run python if you wish.

Comment: So in this case, I would be responsible for running my own http host, database, etc.?  The flexibility certainly seems desirable, but I am not a linux sysadmin, and it would be better if someone that is smarter than I could take care of those things...

Answer (score 3):

Microsoft Windows Azure might be worth consideration. I'm afraid I haven't used it so can't say if it's any good and you should bear in mind that it's a CTP at the moment.

[Check it out here.](http://www.microsoft.com/azure/services.mspx)

Answer (score 3):

You may also want to take a look at [AWS Elastic Beanstalk](http://aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/) - it has a closer equivalence to GAE functionality, in that it is designed to be PaaS, rather than an IaaS (i.e. EC2)

Answer (score 3):

A bit late, but I would give Heroku a go:

> Heroku is a polyglot cloud application platform. With Heroku, you
>   don’t need to think about servers at all. You can write apps using
>   modern development practices in the programming language of your
>   choice, back it with add-on resources such as SQL and NoSQL databases,
>   Memcached, and many others. You manage your app using the Heroku
>   command-line tool and you deploy code using the Git revision control
>   system, all running on the Heroku infrastructure.

https://www.heroku.com/about

Answer (score 2):

If you're interested in the cloud, and maybe want to create your own for production and/or testing you have to look at [Eucalyptus](http://ostatic.com/blog/eucalyptus-an-unsung-open-source-infrastructure-for-cloud-computing). It's allegedly code compatible with EC2 but open source.

Comment: need a link to http://code.google.com/p/appscale/

Answer (score 1):

I'd be more interested in seeing how App Engine can be easily coupled with another server used for CPU intensive requests.

Comment: Agreed - With the data stored in BigTable, could another server perhaps hit a simple web service that would return small chunks of data, do the heavy lifting, and return the finished report?  I have actually considered moving some of this type of thing into flash, using the same approach.

Answer (score 1):

[TyphoonAE](http://code.google.com/p/typhoonae/) is trying to do this. I haven't tested it, but while it is still in beta, it looks like it's atleast in active development.

Answer (score 0):

The shift to cloud computing is happening so rapidly that you have no time to waste for testing different platforms. 
I suggest you trying out [Jelastic](http://jelastic.com/) if you are interested in Java as well.

One of the greatest things about Jelastic is that you do not need to make any changes in the code of your application, except the changes for your application functionality, but not for the reason the chosen platform demands this. With reference to this you do not actually waste your time.The deployment process is just flawless, and you can deploy your .war file anywhere further.Using GAE requires you to modify the app around their system needs. In case if you happen to get working with Java and start looking for a more flexible platform, Jelastic is a compatible alternative.

Answer (score 0):

You can also use Red Hat's Cape Dwarf project, to run GAE apps on top of the Wildfly appserver (previously JBoss) without modification.

You can check it out here:

http://capedwarf.org/