# Uploading google apps engine to web hosting

Tags: google-app-engine

Hi I'm new on google apps engine platform, I use python, and after follow the course on udacity.com I found that the site is uploaded to appspot, I just want to know that the website I made only avalible on appspot? or I can hosting it on my own web hosting.
thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Nope you cannot use it on your own hosting without loosing a lot of features, and not really using the NDB (except if you connect to the datastore via dev)

Check [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/153721/what-alternatives-are-there-to-google-app-engine) for alternatives.

I recommend [AppScale](https://github.com/AppScale/appscale)