# Google App Engine for pseudo-cronjobs?

Tags: python, google-app-engine, cron

I look for a possibility to create pseudo-cronjobs as I cannot use the real jobs on UNIX.

Since Python scripts can run for an unlimited period, I thought Python would be a great solution.

On Google App Engine you can set up Python scripts and it's free. So I should use the App Engine.

The App Engine allows 160,000 external URL accesses (right?) so you should have 160000/31/24/60 = 3,6 accesses per minute.

So my script would be:

```
import time
import urllib
while time.clock() < 86400:
    # execute pseudo-cronjob file and then wait 60 seconds
    content = urllib.urlopen('http://www.example.org/cronjob_file.php').read()
    time.sleep(60)
```

Unfortunately, I have no possibility to test the script, so my questions are:
1) Do you think this would work?
2) Is it allowed (Google TOS) to use the service for such an activity?
3) Is my calculation for the URL accesses per minute right?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Cron jobs on AppEngine are limited to the Request time limit, which is 30 seconds - so it cannot run 'for an unlimited period'.

Comment: Sorry, what do you exactly mean by that? I think Python itself has no time limit, has it? The only reqeust time limit is in the client's browser. But if you execute the file by cronjobs there is no client. Or does Google App Engine have an own request time limit to avoid scripts running to long?

Comment: Actually, the time limit is imposed on the server side so yes, this avoids scripts taking too much time.

Comment: You should probably take a look at the quotas page: http://code.google.com/appengine/docs/quotas.html.   Yes - GAE does have a request limit to avoid scripts running too long.  Currently it is 30 seconds.

Comment: Thanks. I think with that limits GAE isn't very useful for having the scripts running there. But I can use GAE to trigger the scripts on my webspace.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Maybe I'm misunderstanding you, but the cron config files will let you do this (without Python).
You can add something like this to you cron.yaml file:

```
cron:
- description: job that runs every minute
  url: /cronjobs/job1
  schedule: every minute
```

See [Google's documentation](http://code.google.com/appengine/docs/python/config/cron.html#About_cron_yaml) for more info on scheduling.

Comment: No, you're not misunderstanding me. I didn't know that there is a cron job service now. But I can't add external URLs to the cron job service, can I? So I must still use a Python script which invokes the external file. Right?

Answer (score 2):

Google has some limits on how long a task can run.

URLFetch calls made in the SDK now have a 5 second timeout, [here](http://googleappengine.blogspot.com/2008/11/sdk-116-released.html)

They allow you to schedule up to 20 cron tasks in any given day.  [Here](http://code.google.com/appengine/docs/python/config/cron.html)

Comment: Thanks, so it isn't very suitable for creating pseudo cron jobs.

Answer (score 1):

Duplicate, see [cron jobs on google appengine](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/145651/cron-jobs-on-google-appengine)

Cron jobs are now officaly supported on GAE:
http://code.google.com/appengine/docs/python/config/cron.html

Comment: I don't know. Maybe because coonj answered the question before!? I'm not the downvoter.

Answer (score 1):

You may want to clarify which way around you want to do it

Do you want to use appengine to RUN the job? Ie, the job runs on google's server?

or

Do you want to use your OWN code on your server, and trigger it by using google app engine?

If it's the former: google does cron now. Use that :)

If it's the latter: you could use google's cron to trigger your own, even if it's indirectly (ie, google-cron calls google-app-engine which calls your-app).

If you can, spin up a thread to do the job, so your page returns immediatly. Dont forgot: if you call http://whatever/mypage.php, and your browser dies (or in this case, google kills your process for running too long), the php script usually still runs to the end - the output just goes no where.

Failing that, try to spin up a thread (not sure if you can do that in PHP tho - I'm a C# guy new to PHP)

And if all else fails: get a better webhost! I pay $6/month or so for dreamhost.com, and I can run cron jobs on their servers - it's included. They do PHP, Rails et al. You could even ping me for a discount code :) (view profile for website etc)

Comment: Thank you very much! I want it to work in the second way you mentioned. It should just trigger the script on my external website. But am I allowed to use Google App Engine just for triggering my cron jobs (Terms of service)?

Comment: I've not read the TOS that closely, but I can't see why not. It's just a URL call, which I think you are allowed to do.

Answer (score 0):

Do what Nic Wise said or also outsource the cronjob using a service like www.guardiano.pm so you can actually call www.yoursite.com/myjob.php and every time you call that url something you want will be executed.

Ps is free
Pss is my pet project and is in beta