# Cron job (sending email) in Google App Engine

Tags: python, google-app-engine, cron

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [cron jobs on google appengine](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/145651/cron-jobs-on-google-appengine)

I have created a Google App Engine app using Python for weekly project and assessment reporting.

I want to check on Fridays who has submitted the report so that I can send a notification email on Monday to those who haven't submitted the report.

Any suggestions on how to set up this cron job?

Answer (score 2):

You can schedule the task using the [App Engine Scheduled Tasks](http://code.google.com/appengine/docs/python/config/cron.html) feature.

You'll need to add an entry to the `cron.yaml` file for your application.  Something like:

```
cron:
- description: friday mailout
  url: /mail/weekly
  schedule: every friday 09:00
```

You can send email using the [App Engine Mail API](http://code.google.com/appengine/docs/python/mail/sendingmail.html).